# Overlay on a bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put an overlay div on a bootstrap panel.

Here my html :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navi">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3><asp:label runat="server" id="lblsecretquestion"></asp:label></h3>
                <h4>Saisissez la réponse de votre question secrète :</h4>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alerterror" style="display:none;position:relative;">
                    <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.
                </div>
                <div id="divtxtanswer" class="form-group">
                    <input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" class="form-control " id="txtanswer" placeholder="Answer" />
                </div>
                <p id="errortxtanswer" style="color:Red;display:none;">Answer error</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoi"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my css :

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#navi, 
#infoi {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#infoi {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I am stuck. I don't know how I can achieve this, especially with bootstrap. Here's is the fiddle of my attempt : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxv6L/151/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yxv6L/152/ 

Is this what you mean by overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `position` property of an element to `absolute`, you remove the element from the normal flow and it becomes relative to its closest ancestor element that has the `position` set to either `relative` or `absolute`, or the entire `body` in case there's no positioned ancestor. In your case, in order to make the absolute positioned element recognize percentage values, you have to define the properties you want it to be relative (`width` and `height`) to the `body`.

Add this rule to your css:

```
html, body {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxv6L/153/)

Hope it helps.